# Error with embedded statements

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
if (RdoBtnBeepDefault.Checked) SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
else SoundPlayer iPlay = new SoundPlayer(@TxtBeepFile.Text);

iPlay.Play();
```

And here's the error:

`Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement`

If that isn't possible, mind telling me how?

Comment: The error is because you can't declare a variable (`iPlay`) in a single-statement if/else, unless you use `{ braces }`. (I think the language was designed that way to avoid scope ambiguity...)

Answer (score 9):

`iPlay.Play();` is beyond the scope of your `else` clause in your `if-else` statement. Try enclosing it with braces for multiple line scope.

```
if (RdoBtnBeepDefault.Checked) 
{
    SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
)
else
{ 
    SoundPlayer iPlay = new SoundPlayer(TxtBeepFile.Text);
    iPlay.Play();
)
```

Comment: This is biggest reason I would suggest that you **always use braces even with one line**.

Comment: @PreetSangha even if I have one line for each if-else clause, I used to enclose it in a braces. :D I don't know why I can't keep myself from doing that.. hhehe

Answer (score 3):

Not only that even this can produce the same error

```
if (RdoBtnBeepDefault.Checked) SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
else int i=0;
```

The reason is logic. If you put a single line statement in if else condition which indirectly means the conditional flow is ending with that line. In that case if you use some declaration||something as above which won't make sense/impact in any way, then that means It is kind of string literal. It is not exactly wrong, rather it is unneccessary. Mind c# visual studio editor reduces almost all the possible errors and unneccessary memory loading.

When you put braces, it indiactes that you may use that variable within the same block for some logic. So the editor will allow you to do that. At that time the VS assumes you may add the code in future. So it will give you only warning about that line. Without braces it is solidly assuming that you are not going to use that variable(due to scope).So, it takes that as error.